# Azure SubDomain Link to Appservice

Tags: azure, dns, subdomain, web-hosting

I have domain example.com I bought in azure.And I have two appservices app1 and app2.

I can link example.com to app1

But I want to link example.com/one to app1(appservices)
and example.com/two to app2(appservices).

Can anyone plz suugest me how to do this in Microsoft Azure

Comment: Have you looked at using subdomains like app1.example.com and app2.example.com?

Answer (score 2):

Using [**Azure Application Gateway**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview) and creating the relevant routing rules would be a good way to do this.

Here's a quick screenshot from Microsoft Docs which talks about a similar scenario..

[image]

Do know that there is price associated with it (and a lot of other features). So you may need to evaluate a bit.
[Application Gateway Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/application-gateway/)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to assign the custom domain to a load balancer.  [Azure App Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview) supports [URL based routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-url-route-arm-ps).  Since Azure App Services are multi-tenant you will need to follow these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-web-app) to configure App Gateway with an App Server.  This is a great solution for single region applications.

If you need mutli-region support, check out our new [Azure Front Door Service](http://Azure%20Front%20Door%20Service%20enables%20you%20to%20define,%20manage,%20and%20monitor%20the%20global%20routing%20for%20your%20web%20traffic%20by%20optimizing%20for%20best%20performance%20and%20instant%20global%20failover%20for%20high%20availability.%20With%20Front%20Door,%20you%20can%20transform%20your%20global%20(multi-region)%20consumer%20and%20enterprise%20applications%20into%20robust,%20high-performance%20personalized%20modern%20applications,%20APIs,%20and%20content%20that%20reach%20a%20global%20audience%20with%20Azure.). Azure Front Door Service enables you to define, manage, and monitor the global routing for your web traffic by optimizing for best performance and instant global failover for high availability. With Front Door, you can transform your global (multi-region) consumer and enterprise applications into robust, high-performance personalized modern applications, APIs, and content that reach a global audience with Azure.